# Perplexed by mixins and $variables in Sass

Tags: sass, mixins

Sass newbie here. Playing with mixins. Something is not right:

```
$> sass -v
Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve)

$> cat myscss.scss

// Keyframe animations
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
}

@include keyframes(move-up) {
  0% {
    top: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


$> sass myscss.scss
@-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
  0% {
    top: 25px;
    opacity: 1; }
  100% {
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0; } }
```

And this is the problem. I was expecting:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move-up {
  0% {
    top: 25px;
    opacity: 1; }
  100% {
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0; } }
```

What am I missing?

Please bear with my adding or meaningless text here. Apparently stackoverflow won't let me post my question because they see too much code and too little text. Hopefully this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around, I see that this does the trick, but why it does, it is not clear to me:

```
@mixin keyframes ($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```